# /dev や /sys にどのようなファイルが入ってるか調べるための方法を知りたい

Tags: linux

Linuxのディレクトリ構成(/dev, /sysにどのようなファイルが格納されているか)について、manやinfoを使って調べたいと思っています。

そこで、以下の２点についてご教授いただけないでしょうか？

1. manやinfoでLinuxのディレクトリ構成についての情報を取得できますでしょうか？
2. manやinfoでLinuxのディレクトリ構成の情報を取得するには、どのような引数を与えればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: manやinfoはオンラインマニュアルを読むツールです。ファイルやディレクトリを調べるには ls, find, file などのコマンドを使います。man ls、man find、man file などを実行して各コマンドのマニュアルを読んでみるとよいでしょう。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

man は主に **コマンドの使い方** を調べるコマンドなので、Linux に関するすべてが調べられるわけではありません。

---

`/dev` や `/sys` など、主にルートディレクトリ直下に配置されているディレクトリ構造については、
**FHS** (Filesystem Hierarchy Standard) という名前で標準化されています。

[Wikipedia の記事](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) にも詳しく載っていますが、より詳細は [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://www.pathname.com/fhs/) のページや、その [日本語訳](http://pocketstudio.jp/linux/?FHS) も確認してみてください。

Comment: FHS の最新版は https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml にあるようです。

Answer (score 10):

> 2. manやinfoでLinuxのディレクトリ構成の情報を取得するには、どのような引数を与えればよいのでしょうか？

```bash
$ man -k 'file system'
            :

file-hierarchy (7)   - File system hierarchy overview

$ man 7 file-hierarchy

FILE-HIERARCHY(7)         file-hierarchy        FILE-HIERARCHY(7)

NAME
       file-hierarchy - File system hierarchy overview

DESCRIPTION
       Operating systems using the systemd(1) system and service
       manager are organized based on a file system hierarchy
       inspired by UNIX, ...

                                 :

GENERAL STRUCTURE
       /
           The file system root. Usually writable, but this is
           not required. Possibly a temporary file system
           ("tmpfs"). Not shared with other hosts (unless
           read-only).

       /boot/
           The boot partition used for bringing up the system. On
           EFI systems, this is possibly the EFI System Partition
           (ESP), also see systemd-gpt-auto-generator(8).

                                 :
```

Answer (score 1):

多くのディストリビューションに以下のような man ページがあります。

- `/dev`: `man udev`
  （`/dev` の管理はディストリピューションによりますが、最近は主に `udev` が担当しています）
- `/sys`: `man 5 sysfs`
- `/proc`: `man proc`